# In Python, how can I test if I'm in Google App Engine SDK?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Whilst developing I want to handle some things slight differently than I will when I eventually upload to the Google servers.

Is there a quick test that I can do to find out if I'm in the SDK or live?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

See: [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-requests-are-handled#Python_The_environment](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Environment)

> The following environment variables are part of the CGI standard, with special behavior in App Engine:
>   `SERVER_SOFTWARE`:
>
> In the **development web server**, this value is "`Development/X.Y`" where "`X.Y`" is the version of the runtime.
>
> **When running on App Engine**, this value is "`Google App Engine/X.Y.Z`".

Comment: Thanks 

something like this works for me now:

import os
def development():
    if os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].find('Development') == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

Comment: It's eaten my formatting in the comment, but you know what I mean. Cheers

Comment: Simpler: os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Development')

Comment: Also, in AppScale (open source GAE) this value is set to "AppScaleServer/X.Y".

Comment: This is different for the Python 3 runtime: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime. I wanted to use NODE_ENV and the value "production", but it wasn't there, so I used GAE_DEPLOYMENT_ID... The docs must be incorrect, or I don't understand when NODE_ENV is set

Comment: This answer may not apply to python3 environment. Check the other answers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67974075/2023941

Answer (score 8):

In `app.yaml`, you can add `IS_APP_ENGINE` environment variable

```yaml
env_variables:
  IS_APP_ENGINE: 1
```

and in your Python code check if it has been set

```py
if os.environ.get("IS_APP_ENGINE"):
    print("The app is being run in App Engine")
else:
    print("The app is being run locally")
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on the same trick, I use this function in my code:

```
def isLocal():
    return os.environ["SERVER_NAME"] in ("localhost", "www.lexample.com")
```

I have customized my `/etc/hosts` file in order to be able to access the local version by prepending a "l" to my domain name, that way it is really easy to pass from local to production.

Example:

- production url is `www.example.com`
- development url is `www.lexample.com`

Comment: I prefer `w3` subdomain for local. `w3.example.com` and `www.example.com`

Answer (score 3):

I just check the httplib (which is a wrapper around appengine fetch)

```
def _is_gae():
   import httplib
   return 'appengine' in str(httplib.HTTP)
```

Comment: I wanted to point out that 'appengine' is no longer the string returned by `str(httplib.HTTP)` when inside of App Engine.  The actual string is `gae_override.httplib.HTTP`.  Update test to `return 'gae_override' in str(httplib.HTTP)`

Answer (score 3):

The current suggestion from [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app#detecting_application_runtime_environment) is:

```
if os.getenv('GAE_ENV', '').startswith('standard'):
  # Production in the standard environment
else:
  # Local execution.
```

Comment: This answer is supported by the tests run in the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64592250/2023941 indicating the other answers are out of date.

Answer (score 2):

**A more general solution**
A more general solution, which does not imply to be on a Google server,  detects if the code is running on your local machine.
I am using the code below regardless the hosting server:

```
import socket

if socket.gethostname() == "your local computer name":
    DEBUG = True
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1", "localhost", ]
    ...
else:
    DEBUG = False
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [".your_site.com",]
    ...
```

If you use macOS you could write a more generic code:

```
if socket.gethostname().endswith(".local"): # True in your local computer
    ...
```

Django developers must put this sample code in the file `settings.py` of the project.

EDIT:
According to Jeff O'Neill in macOS High Sierra `socket.gethostname()` returns a string ending in ".lan".

Comment: For latest Mac OS X, the proper suffix now seems to be ".lan".

Comment: Interesting, I just move to Sierra last week and `socket.gethostname()` returns a string ending with ".local".
Are you running High Sierra or a server version of macOS?

Comment: I just upgraded to High Sierra so must be that.

Answer (score 2):

Update on October 2020: 
I tried using `os.environ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]` and `os.environ["APPENGINE_RUNTIME"]` but both didn't work so I just logged all keys from the results from `os.environ`.
In these keys, there was `GAE_RUNTIME` which I used to check if I was in the local environment or cloud environment. 
The exact key might change or you could add your own in `app.yaml` but the point is, log `os.environ`, perhaps by adding to a list in a test webpage, and use its results to check your environment.