# How can my code tell if it's running on Google's server or my local development server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Python, how can I test if I'm in Google App Engine SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916579/in-python-how-can-i-test-if-im-in-google-app-engine-sdk)

Is there an environment flag that will tell if my code is running in production or on the development server?

I'd like to be able to use an if statement to do something different depending on this flag.

(Specific case: newlines in a text file I want to read are treated differently in the two environments.)

Answer (score 17):

```
if os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE','').startswith('Development'):
    DEBUG = True
    logging.debug("[*] Debug info activated")
```

Comment: **thats a way to go** - too bad google does not provide a simple funncion like that one :( Just look after SERVER_SOFTWARE in google_appengine SDK and you will find ~8 calls doing that test

Comment: The `$SERVER_SOFTWARE` env. var. seems to be missing from App Engine Standard ([here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#environment_variables)) and Flexible ([here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#environment_variables)) default env. var. in 2021.  Use `$GAE_ENV` if you **must** depend on a default env. var.  I would **highly** recommend defining env. var. in your `app.yaml` file (further reading [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref)).

Answer (score 1):

For Google App Engine, since I've been told that you can't import socket you could probably use that fact to determine if you're running on GAE.  This solution isn't 100% foolproof, but it should do what you want.  Put this in settings.py.

```
try:
    import socket
except ImportError:
    DEBUG = TRUE
```

For anyone using Django but not GAE, you can use this instead.  Change 'devserver' to whatever the hostname of your development server is.

```
import socket
if socket.gethostname() == 'devserver':
    DEBUG = TRUE
```

Then wherever you need to check the DEBUG variable in your code

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    newline = '\n'
```

Comment: I don't think app engine allows you to import socket.  You may want to edit your post so the wrong information isn't spread. (I upvoted  you because I don't think people should downvote and not give a reason.)

Comment: Oh thanks.  I don't use GAE, but this does work for plain Django.  I didn't realize how limited GAE was.