# Appengine development server sendmail error - want to supress

Tags: python, google-app-engine, smtp

I have an AppEngine Python/Django application that sends a confirmation email upon registration. I do not have an SMTP server setup locally, and I do not have any plans to setup a local server.

Because I do not have an SMTP server setup locally, when I register a new user on the development server, the program generates the following error: "SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first".

According to the AppEngine documentation at: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver Quote: "If mail is not enabled with either SMTP or Sendmail, then attempts to send email from the application will do nothing, and appear successful in the application."

How can I either (1) supress these error messages when the mail fails on the development server, or (2) prevent the server from trying to send emails? Is the documentation correct?

Since my app sends emails from a task queue, this failure results in retries which generates a lot of error messages, which makes it difficult for me to see the relevant information in the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are correct, but they're referring to the [App Engine mail API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/). Based on your error message, it looks like you're using smtplib (probably via a Django module) which tries to connect to the SMTP server directly. The best you can do is probably to [detect when running on the dev server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782332/how-can-my-code-tell-if-its-running-on-googles-server-or-my-local-development) and catch the exception you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks. Come to think of it, I probably started seeing this error when I upgraded to Django-Nonrel from AppEngine Helper. Thanks for pointin me in the right direction.