# Google App Engine: Development only route in app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to create a route that is recognised only when using a local development server? I'm wanting to create a static_dir route in app.yaml but I only need it for testing.

Comment: What's the harm to simply add it, if it's never called in production?

Comment: It is not that big of a problem just a little messy. For example if someone accidentally leaves something in the directory then it would be accessible to the public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding/removing a static route in app.yaml, create a script/servlet that processes these requests - or ignores them if they come from the production domain.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean, can you post an example of app.yaml?

Comment: Instead of adding/removing a static route in app.yaml, create a script/servlet that processes these requests - or ignores them if they come from the production domain.

Comment: Right, yeah that's what I ended up doing. A little less clean but it works. Mind if I change your answer to the above comment? I think it makes more sense that your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do that. The closest solution I can imagine is to use `login: admin` but I am not it works with `static_dir`. The documentation is [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Requiring_login_or_administrator_status).

If it does not work, you might need to check the environment in your request handler. Please take a look at [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4782584/1822624)