# How to determine if your app is running on local Python Development Server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to programatically determine if my app is running in development or not, so that I can provide sandbox values for a variety of constants and methods.

Something like:

```
if app.development: # Live mode
  FREEBASE_USER = "spam123"
  FREEBASE_PSWD = "eggs123"
  FREEBASE = freebase

else: # Sandbox mode
  FREEBASE_USER = "spam"
  FREEBASE_PSWD = "eggs"
  FREEBASE = freebase.sandbox
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916579/in-python-how-can-i-test-if-im-in-google-app-engine-sdk

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
import os

DEV = os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Development')
```

Comment: os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] was missing in our os.environ dictionary (Mac), but os.environ['PYCHARM_HOSTED'] was present and == "1" which was good enough to recognize our dev environment.