# Python App Engine debug/dev mode

Tags: python, google-app-engine, testing, development-environment

I'm working on an App Engine project (Python) where we'd like to make certain changes to the app's behavior when debugging/developing (most often locally). For example, when debugging, we'd like to disable our rate-limiting decorators, turn on the debug param in the WSGIApplication, maybe add some asserts.

As far as I can tell, App Engine doesn't naturally have any concept of a global dev-mode or debug-mode, so I'm wondering how best to implement such a mode. The options I've been able to come up with so far:

1. Use `google.appengine.api.app_identity.get_default_version_hostname()` to get the hostname and check if it begins with `localhost`. This seems... unreliable, and doesn't allow for using the debug mode in a deployed app instance.
2. Use `os.environ.get('APPLICATION_ID')` to get the application id, which according to [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_Application_IDs_in_the_development_web_server) is automatically prepended with `dev~` by the development server. Worryingly, the very source of this information is in a box warning:

   > Do not get the App ID from the environment variable. The development
   >   server simulates the production App Engine service. One way in which
   >   it does this is to prepend a string (`dev~`) to the `APPLICATION_ID`
   >   environment variable, which is similar to the string prepended in
   >   production for applications using the High Replication Datastore. You
   >   can modify this behavior with the --default_partition flag, choosing a
   >   value of "" to match the master-slave option in production. Google
   >   recommends always getting the application ID using get_application_id,
   >   as described above.

   Not sure if this is an acceptable use of the environment variable. Either way it's probably equally hacky, and suffers the same problem of only working with a locally running instance.
3. Use a custom app-id for development (locally and deployed), use the `-A` flag in `dev_appserver.py`, and use `google.appengine.api.app_identity.get_application_id()` in the code. I don't like this for a number of reasons (namely having to have two separate app engine projects).
4. Use a `dev` app engine [version](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?csw=1#Python_app_yaml_Required_elements) for development and detect with `os.environ.get('CURRENT_VERSION_ID').split('.')[0]` in code. When deployed this is easy, but I'm not sure how to make dev_appserver.py use a custom version without modifying app.yaml. I suppose I could `sed` app.yaml to a temp file in `/tmp/` with the version replaced and the relative paths resolved (or just create a persistent dev-app.yaml), then pass that into dev_appserver.py. But that seems also kinda dirty and prone to error/sync issues.

Am I missing any other approaches? Any considerations I failed to acknowledge? Any other advice?

Comment: you can specify the app.yaml file you want to use when using dev_appserver.py just by specifying it on the command line. I have, for example, local SQL settings in development.yaml but when deployed it automatically switches to app.yaml

Comment: Yep, that's assumed as part of #4.

Comment: Why does option 1 "seem" unreliable. And how does that preclude using debug mode. Surely the control of debug mode would be independent of where it's running dev or production?

Comment: why not use just the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916579/in-python-how-can-i-test-if-im-in-google-app-engine-sdk

Comment: @TimHoffman: I guess I just don't know how the app is run in prod and method #1 defines dev-mode in terms of where it's running. I agree it should be independent, though.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood: That's probably the most correct if I'm ok with not supporting a deployed dev mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regards to "detecting" localhost development we use the following in our applications settings / config file.

```
IS_DEV_APPSERVER = 'development' in os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').lower()
```

That used in conjunction with the debug flag should do the trick for you.