# Under GAE, can a Python function detect if it is running locally or in production?

Tags: google-app-engine

I need my app to run very slightly differently depending on whether it is running on the GAE launcher on my laptop or really inside GAE.  The app-id is the same, the app.yaml is the same, is there something different I can see?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how can I test if I'm in Google App Engine SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916579/in-python-how-can-i-test-if-im-in-google-app-engine-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of this documentation on handling requests https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/requests#Python_The_environment specifically the section on the environment.

You will see a number of potentially relevant environment variables.  The one you want is **SERVER_SOFTWARE** . It will contain "Development" in the value.

Also this has been answered before on SO. [In Python, how can I test if I'm in Google App Engine SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916579/in-python-how-can-i-test-if-im-in-google-app-engine-sdk)