# How to check whether if I'm running the code on a GCP / AWS instance?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

is there a way to perform a check to indicate on which platform I am? what I mean by that is not that I want to check whether it's `Linux` or `Darwin` I mean I need to check whether I am on a cloud instance, I use GCP and AWS so I need some accurate way.

The only answers I found are in some very old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916579/in-python-how-can-i-test-if-im-in-google-app-engine-sdk) which checks using `os.environ()` for a `SERVER_NAME` which I tried and it does not work. I may hardcode a check for my ip address maybe or anything that works only for me but I think there is a clean solution.

Answer (score 2):

This might change over years, But around 2022 i use below method to check who is the service provider.

`ipinfo` provides a json result of server basic details. then you can identify using `hostname` or `org`

```
curl ipinfo.io

"hostname": "x.x.x.x.bc.googleusercontent.com",
"hostname": "ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
"org": "x Microsoft Corporation"
```

Answer (score 1):

For a reliable way, I'd do a query for the external IP address (provided that the instance has internet connectivity), such as using https://ifconfig.me/ , then check if the answer is in the the AWS/GCP IP address range (for AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html, I don't know about GCP).

Comment: Only to complement this answer, you could find the GCP IP Range in this  URL: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#find_ip_range

Comment: I'll try doing that and let you know

Answer (score 0):

As long as the hostnames are set for both hosts, you could get the current hostname of the machine the code is running on by using `sockets`:

```
import socket
print(socket.gethostname())
```

Comment: it returns the name of GCP instance, which varies of course, did not try it on AWS but I think it will be pretty much the same thing, are there better ways?

Comment: Is there a naming convention to the GCP and AWS instances that would make them identifiable from one another? Are you able to set the hostname of your machine on GCP - I am not familiar with the service.

Comment: No, as far as I know there is nothing distinctive that I can think of

Answer (score 0):

Both AWS and GCP use the same URL for instance metadata: http://169.254.169.254

However, the contents that is returned is different. So, you can use that information to determine whether code is running on a cloud system, and which one.

Comment: Just go to http://169.254.169.254. For example, `curl http://169.254.169.254`

Comment: Okay, I'll check and let you know