# Google Cloud Django if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'): not working

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am working on a Google Cloud Django Project.

I am trying to check in `settings.py` if I am running in Development or Production mode.

I added the following block of code to test if the SOFTWARE where the program is running either is on my machine or on Google Cloud Servers.

```py
# | settings.py |
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):
    #code to execute in production
else:
    #code to execute in development
```

I noticed that the `if` statment is **always** *false*, so I decited to debug the `os.environ` dict.
The result of the debug is that the value of the key *SERVER_SOFTWARE* of the enviroment is equal to ***gunicorn/20.1.0***.

As written in the correct answer of this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916579/in-python-how-can-i-test-if-im-in-google-app-engine-sdk), when running on production (so on Google Cloud Severs App Engine), the value of *SERVER_SOFTWARE* should be ***Google App Engine/X.Y.Z***, where X, Y and Z represent the version of Google Cloud. But, as I said, my value, when running on App Engine, is not like that, it is ***gunicorn/20.1.0***.

So, how do I make the program know if I am running either in development or production?

Comment: Is your Django application running in the App Engine Standard or Flexible (AEF) environment?  The answer your linked mentions App Engine Standard env. only.

Comment: I guess that I am running on the standard one

Comment: You said - you guess. Can you confirm? Check if you have ```env: flex``` in your app.yaml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll present a couple other solutions.

**(1) GAE provided env vars**

GAE automatically sets environment variables that you probably don't set when running locally.  I use this:

```
version = os.environ.get('GAE_VERSION', 'local')
```

You'll get the actual version in production and 'local' on your machine.

**(2) Check the request URL**

This is Flask but there must be something similar in Django:

```
request.url_root == 'http://localhost:8080/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the Stack Overflow (SO) answer you linked to is almost twelve years old and refers to Python 2 (deprecated).  I was unable to find the `SYSTEM_SOFTWARE` default env. var. for both the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) App Engine Standard ([here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#environment_variables)) and Flexible environment ([here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#environment_variables)).

It's safe to say that the env. var. that App Engine injects into every Standard instance by default *can* change.  Instead, why don't you supply an env. var. in your App Engine Standard env. configuration file (`app.yaml`) to make sure that your Django application is running in "production" only when you want it to:

1. Add the `env_variables` section to `app.yaml`, such as:

   ```yaml
   . . .
   env_variables:
     DJANGO_PRODUCTION_ENVIRONMENT: true
   . . .
   ```

   or:

   ```yaml
   . . .
   env_variables:
     DJANGO_SYSTEM_SOFTWARE: "production"
   . . .
   ```

   You can look into more App Engine Standard env. config. settings [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref).
2. Deploy your Django application to App Engine Standard env. with the GCP Cloud SDK (`gcloud`):

   ```sh
   gcloud app deploy --appyaml=./app.yaml
   ```

Confirm that older versions (e.g., `$AES_OLD_VERSION`) have stopped with:

```sh
gcloud app versions list \
--format="table[box=true](version.id:label=ID, version.servingStatus:label=STATUS)" \
--service=$AES_SERVICE_ID
┌──────────────────┬─────────┐
│        ID        │  STATUS │
├──────────────────┼─────────┤
│      . . .       │  . . .  │
│ $AES_OLD_VERSION │ STOPPED │
│ $AES_VERSION_ID  │ SERVING │
└──────────────────┴─────────┘
```

Confirm that your env. var. have made it into `$AES_VERSION_ID` with:

```sh
gcloud app versions describe $AES_VERSION_ID \
--format="yaml(envVariables)" \
--service=$AES_SERVICE_ID

#=>

envVariables:
  DJANGO_PRODUCTION_ENVIRONMENT: 'True'
  DJANGO_SYSTEM_SOFTWARE: production
```